# multi-relational Database Model with multi-requests

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, orm, relational-database

I have a table "USERS"
I have a table "HOUSES"
I have a table "CALENDAR"
I have a table "TRANSACTIONS"

I need build a schedule(CALENDAR) that relates to every home, every home has days available for purchase, days that were purchased, days that are not available for purchase.

which in turn, also relate to users who bought, and users who are homeowners

and there is a table of transactions, so one day it is purchased, the calendar table changes the days that were available to bought, to purchased, and also shows those same days in the transaction table.

What better way to make this relationship? I thought I'd create a table calendar, with 366 days of the year as columns, and each row a house with three possible values: available to buy, bought, not available. What do you suggest?

Comment: just focusing on a little concept here. How about a house table with simple entity info, perhaps including a `startForSale` date datatype, and an `endForSale` date, and a `reasonCode` for why the end happened (Sale, TakenOff, etc). The 366 column thing wouldn't survive a great peer-review

Comment: But, a house have many dates for sale, and not continuous dates, perhaps a relation with a table houseSaleDates with HouseID, startForSale, endForSale? having a house multiples start-end dates for sale

Comment: no problem at all if that is real-world. A 1-2-many tho

Comment: students and classes are many-to-many. houses and their date ranges are 1 to many (they don't share ranges)

Comment: 366 columns? No. One row per day. Learn how to normalised your data.